# What does "not everyone is born with their tails facing the moon" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, idioms

Context:
Someone compared a Hollywood singer with a Portuguese singer on YouTube (The Voice Portugal). They said that this international singer still sang her original song better than the contestant. Then, a commentor replied to his comment:
"American-type comment, egocentric. US is not the center of the universe, much less American singers. There are also very good singers in Portugal. But since they don't live in Hollywood, they can't show their value...**not everyone is born with their tails facing the moon**."

For me, this phrase means privileged. What do you think?

Comment: It's a colourful expression and from context it makes sense. But neither I, nor (my) Google, have heard it before.  I guess it is a translation of a Portuguese (?) expression. It seems likely from the context that the commenter is not a native speaker.  Anyway, please provide a direct link to the comment, so we can see it in context.

Comment: @JamesK - change 'tail' for 'ass' in your search and you'll see it in plenty!

Comment: “Avoir le cul bordé de nouilles” is a similar French expression that translates literally to “to have one's ass lined with noodles'.

Answer (score 3):

The expression appears to be a translation of the Portuguese *nasceu com o cu virado para a lua*, often translated less politely as 'born with the ass (or arse) facing the moon'. It is an idiom meaning 'to be extremely lucky in life', with a possible nuance of that 'luck' being the product of circumstances of the person's birth. The Portuguese *cu* inhabits the same sort of register (vulgar) as *cul* and *culo* in other Romance languages. The use of a vulgar word for the posterior, and the choice of that for a part or orifice of the body in a figurative expression, may often signify scorn or derision, as seems to be the case here.